# Problem with user authentication via psql

Tags: psql

I am relatively new to db administration in postgre, and I am loosing tons of time trying to figure out what I am doing wrong here. My goal is to create a user, a db, and to connect to that db from under that user.

What I am doing for that is the following:

```
sudo -u postgres psql
postgres=# create database mydb;
postgres=# create user anna with encrypted password 'anna';
postgres=# grant all privileges on database mydb to anna;
```

Here is all sucess.
Then I try to connect to db this way:

```
sudo -u anna psql mydb
```

And I end up in a strange error:

> sudo: unknown user: anna
>
> sudo: unable to initialize policy plugin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `-u` option of `sudo` specifies an operating system user, not a database user.

Instead, use the `-U` option of `psql`:

```sh
sudo -u postgres psql -U anna -d mydb
```

This will not work if `pg_hba.conf` is configured for `peer` authentication on local connections, unless you specify an additional name mapping.

Comment: Could you please tell me why `psql -h 127.0.0.1 -p 5433 -U anna` does not work then ? It says: `psql: error: FATAL:  database "anna" does not exist`

Comment: Because you didn't specify the database with `-d mydb`. The database defaults to the same value as the database user name.